# Embedding Base64 content into HTML in C#

Tags: c#, html, base64

We use CRM Dynamics to store our files' content as `Base64` string. Files can be of almost any kind (doc, docx, pdf, txt, jpg, png, etc).

When we fetch a record from the CRM we generate a report (HTML) based on information stored in said record (i.e its fields). We use *NReco PDF Generator* to generate our PDF.

We would like to add an ability to also support all the files associated with said record.

If all the files were of Image type (jpeg, jpg, png) it would be as easy as adding an `<img/>` tag with `src="data:..."`.

Unfortunately this isn't the case.

So the question remains, is there any way of embedding `Base64` content in HTML ?

Relevant code:

```
foreach (Entity en in res.Entities)
{
   string base64 = en.GetAttributeValue<string>("documentbody");
}
```

Comment: Forget the base64 bit for now, tell me how you'd embed a normal binary docx(or whatever "other" kind of file you have) into HTML in a meaningful way that the browser(/HTML render engine) can understand, interpret and usefully render..

Comment: We thought we could, somehow, convert the file to an image and then embed it. Is that possible?

Comment: What if the doc has many pages. Would that be one large image? Several images? ...

Comment: Sure you can. You might not want to do it yoursel though; plenty of services out there to do it for low cost

Comment: You could use the leadtools sdk (disclaimer: I work for this company) to convert the base64 into a standard format (PNG or something) and then embed that into an HTML. You could also use the same sdk to convert the base64 straight into PDF without the need for HTML if that suites your needs too. More info can be found here: https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12748-HOW-TO--Handle-Base64-encoded-files-using-the-LEADTOOLS-SDK